# Swap two words in a char* using constant space in less than o(n^2) time

Tags: string, char, c-strings

Given a char* to a string, say containing "hellosir", and the length's of each word,
how can I return a char* containg "sirhello" using constant space in less than o(n^2) time?
(I was asked this in an tech interview)

Function signature:

```
char* swapWords(char* str, int firstWordLen, int secondWordLen);
```

In the "hellosir" example firstWordLen is 5, and secondWordLen is 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
char* swapWords(char* str, int firstWordLen, int secondWordLen) {
    char* newStr = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (firstWordLen + secondWordLen + 1));
    for(int i = 0; i < secondWordLen; i++) {
        newStr[i] = str[firstWordLen + i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < firstWordLen; i++) {
        newStr[secondWordLen + i] = str[i];
    }
    newStr[firstWordLen + secondWordLen] = 0;
    return newStr;
}
```

Explanation:

- Loop over the second word, it starts at the end of word one, so firstWordLen + i, and place the chars at the beginning of the new char array
- Loop over the first word, so from 0 to firstWordLen and place it at the end of the previously placed second word, so at secondWordLen + i
- Add 0 to the end of the new char array because of null termination

Ah ok, this is not constant space my bad, the speed is O(n), but the space is also O(n)

Comment: Yeah the space..